# PHP function returning different data on each call on separate php pages

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am developing a website that has a cart. basically the customer will login and choose what they want and then add it to the cart. this works perfectly. the problem comes when displaying the cart. when i add a product to my cart it adds it successfully (can see it in phpmyadmin), but when view my cart it does not display the product i added. i wait a few minutes it then shows up. i am struggling to find out why it has such a long delay to display.

Here is my php function that i call:

```
function CartGetAll($cid)
{
    $query = "SELECT `cart`.`cart_id`, `cart`.`cart_product`, `cart`.`cart_qty`, `product`.`product_name`, `product`.`product_price`, `product`.`product_image` FROM `product` INNER JOIN `cart` ON `product`.`product_id` = `cart`.`cart_product` WHERE `cart`.`cart_customer` = $cid ORDER BY `product`.`product_name`";
    $result = mysqli_query($this->link, $query);
    $items = array();

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
        $items[] = array('cart_id' => $row['cart_id'], 'cart_product' => $row['cart_product'], 'cart_qty' => $row['cart_qty'], 'product_name' => $row['product_name'], 'product_price' => $row['product_price'], 'product_image' => $row['product_image']);
    }

    return $items;
}
```

EDIT 1:
here is my code where i call the method:

```
require './connection.php';    
$cart = $con->CartGetAll($cid);
```

the $con is the object in the connection class that i use to call all my database functions. $cid is the customer id i pass as a parameter.

EDIT 2:

I forgot to mention that this only happens on the hosted website. When i was developing and testing my website on a local pc with wamp server & netbeans, it never had this issue. only on my online site i get this issue.

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know what s your issue, but if you see it in phpmyadmin it might mean that your php code and functions are working well. So let s assume it is, how do you refresh your cart? do you call your function by ajax and treat callback in js?

Comment: print the query on each call and check if its the expected result @Think_Twice

Comment: Did you debug that single function?Is it returning in expected time?I think a better approach would be to use `$rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);` and then `if($rows){foreach ($rows as $row){ ... } return $items;}`

Comment: It's been a long time since I worked with PHP, in my times this behaviour was a problem with caches. I think that it has been solved by asynchronous mechanisms like AJAX to refresh your page contents, as pointed by Nicolas D. Is it your PHP function "linked" via javascript? Maybe you should check that part.

Comment: Of course thar maybe a caching problem too, is there a server side cache system (db / web pages)? Browser is correctly instructed to make no cache on cart page/url?

Comment: @GiacomoPenuti i tried your code and still the same thing

Comment: @NicolasD  irefresh my cart by calling the method. here is a code snippet: require './connection.php'; $cart = $con->CartGetAll($cid); $cid is the customer id. $con is the object in the connection class i use to call the database methods. i don't use ajax or javascript

Comment: a delay would mean some caching / session problem. CartGetAll is probably fine, where & when you use it though . . .

Comment: @Andrew if it helps i have the following code at the top of my web  page: <?php  session_start(); 
ob_start();
?> could this be the reason? i have that code there because i do use sessions to store temporary data like the customerid etc, and the ob_start(); is there to stop errors when using the header("location:x.php"); to avoid errors from it

Comment: @Think_Twice Yes this helps a lot. session_start() sets also cache headers to `Cache-Control: private, max-age=10800, pre-check=10800` where 10800 is the value of session.cache_expire. Please add this code after session_start():
`session_cache_limiter('private');session_cache_expire(0);`

Comment: Just look where you use CartGetAll / load the cart into session. Is it every time you load the cart? Clearly not. So fix. Make it load at least after every time you add a new item if not on every page load.

Comment: @Andrew basically when they are on the product view page they have a option to select a qty and then add it to the cart. they can then continue shopping or go to their cart. when they go to their cart thats when the product does not display, but in phpmyadmin it does. after about 5 minutes it finally will display. the CartGetAll method is called everytime they view the cart

Comment: but when they load the cart page, does it use the data pulled from db? or just reload the session data, which for some reason gets updated every 5 minutes.

Comment: Did you give my last comment a chance?

Comment: @GiacomoPenuti yes i did try your suggestion. nothing changed

Comment: @Andrew everytime the cart page is loaded i call the CartGetAll function which gets the data from the db. i have been doing more research and it seems to be more of how php is caching the data. is there headers that i can use stop php from caching any data at all?